The Publisher Policy Assembly is no useful？
I created versions 1.0.0.0 and 2.0.0.0 of the library and loaded them into the GAC. I also followed the standard procedure to generate the Publisher Policy Assembly and loaded it into the GAC, hoping the program would automatically reference version 2.0.0.0 of the library. However, every time I run the program, it always loads version 1.0.0.0. What could be the issue?
(.NET framework 4.8.1)
I hope the Publisher Policy Assembly (policy.1.0.xxx) will take effect.
